# Caliburn Micro Custom Event Conventions

Tags: conventions, caliburn.micro

Is it possible to create custom conventions for events in Caliburn Micro? It seems like there's a "default" event for most controls (e.g., "Click" for buttons), but I'd like to create my own conventions for other events (in addition to the defaults).

For instance, I'd like to be able to set up a "SelectionChanged" => "{SelectedItemName}Changed" convention, so I could do something like this:

XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="Items"/>
```

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Items;
public string SelectedItem { get; set; } //Wired automatically by Caliburn

public void SelectedItemChanged() { ... }
```

Most examples I can find just call the method from within the setter for "SelectedItem", but I'd like to avoid that because I use PostSharp to handle my INotifyPropertyChanged updates, so with a convention like this I wouldn't need to remove the auto-properties and replace them with properties + backing fields.

Comment: Not totally related but interesting: http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/243905

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible to create custom convenition for this appropriate case , but you can simply attach SelectionChanged to your ViewModel method using the following syntax:

`<ListView x:Name="Items" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectedItemChanged()]"/>`

In this case you do not need to change SelectedItem property